# Connecting points in a plot if their distance on one axis is below a certain threshold

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, threshold, linestyle

I would like to create a plot where connecting lines are only drawn between points that are closer on one axis than a certain treshold.

Is this possible in MATLAB? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Nan values are skipped during plotting, you can insert nan values to insert gaps in your lines.

Comment: Or I could just use multiple plots. I guess this is a workaround if you only want to plot your data with only one command. Is there a way to do this as I asked?

Comment: Multiple plots would result in multiple entries in the legend.